# How to pass the value from view to controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

here my controller code

```
$data['query']= $this->webpages->get_where_custom('parent_id',0); 
// i  will get $id from view 
$data['query']=$this->webpages->get_where_custom('parent_id',$id);

$this->load->view-(template,$data);
```

in view code i will send $id to controller but its shows undefined variable 'id'

```
   <?php

   foreach($query->result() as $row){
       $id=$row->id;   // how to send this $id to my controller
       $page_url=$row->page_url;
       $parent_id=$row->parent_id;
       $page_headline=$row->page_headline;

  foreach($query->result() as $row){
       $page_url=$row->page_url;
       $page_headline=$row->page_headline;

  ?>
  echo $page headline;
  }
```

}

Comment: Why your are using same name to pass the value in view file for `$data['query']`?

Comment: process the data in controller and render it in view file

Comment: firstly print data on view <?php print_r($data)?> and check the results.

Comment: thanks for quick reply... i am getting the id value in view and how to send the value to controller

Comment: echo site_url("controller/method?id=".$row->id); use this and get the value id from controller using parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of:

```
$this->load->view-(template,$data);
```

Try:

```
$this->load->view(template,$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code look like this

```
$this->load->view('template',$data);
```

and it is because your didn't put $id in the data you put query

so `<?php print_r($query); ?>`